# Data Access Layer to return Data Transformation object

Tags: c#, ado.net

I am trying to create a Data Access Layer using ADO.Net. I have created a generic method for ExecuteNonQuery. The stored procedure I am calling will return two parameters. The output parameters from the stored procedure should be assigned to DTO object and the DTO should need to be returned to BLL.

I am a bit concerned about two things: 1) It is working only when we initialize the output parameters before calling the stored procedure 2) Converting the results to DTO object. Any performance issues?

I am not sure if it's the right approach to return the DTO object to BLL. DBHelper and DBAccess class seems ok to me. I am concerned about the GetRefNo method for the above two questions.

Could anyone please review and let me know if any changes can be made to the existing process.

```
public SubmissionHeaderDTO GetRefNo()
{
    var inPrms = new Dictionary<string, object>()
    {
        {"FormId", Guid.NewGuid()},
        {"FormCode", "TST"},
        {"FormTitle", "Test form"},
        {"User", "test"},
        {"Host", "iisserver"}
    };


    var outPrms = new Dictionary<string, object>() 
    {
        { "SubmissionId", Guid.NewGuid() },
        { "SubmitSequence", "one"}
    };

    var refNo = DBHelper.ExecSP(Constants.SPNames.SubmissionHeaderInsert, inPrms, outPrms);

    SubmissionHeaderDTO result = DictionaryToObject<SubmissionHeaderDTO>(refNo);

    return result;

}
private static T DictionaryToObject<T>(IDictionary<string, object> dict) where T : new()
{
    var t = new T();
    PropertyInfo[] properties = t.GetType().GetProperties();

    foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
    {
        if (!dict.Any(x => x.Key.Equals(property.Name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))
            continue;

        KeyValuePair<string, object> item = dict.First(x => x.Key.Equals(property.Name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));


        Type tPropertyType = t.GetType().GetProperty(property.Name).PropertyType;


        Type newT = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(tPropertyType) ?? tPropertyType;


        object newA = Convert.ChangeType(item.Value, newT);
        t.GetType().GetProperty(property.Name).SetValue(t, newA, null);
    }
    return t;
}
```

DBHelper.cs

```
public static Dictionary<string, object> ExecSP(string sp, Dictionary<string, object> paramIn, Dictionary<string, object> paramOut)
{
    var dbAccess = new DBAccess();
    var results = dbAccess.ExecuteQuery(sp, paramIn, paramOut);
    return results;
}
```

DBAccess.cs

```
public Dictionary<string, object> ExecuteQuery(string storedProcedure, Dictionary<string, object> parameters,
                                              Dictionary<string, object> outParameters)
{
    SqlConnection sqlConn = null;
    SqlCommand sqlcmd = null;
    SqlTransaction transaction = null;
    SqlParameter sqlPar = null;
    Dictionary<string, object> returnParameters = null;

    try
    {
        sqlConn = new SqlConnection(Configuration.DBConnection);
        sqlConn.Open();
        transaction = sqlConn.BeginTransaction("Results");
        sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(storedProcedure, sqlConn, transaction);

        sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> kv in parameters)
        {
            sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(kv.Key, kv.Value);
        }

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> kv in outParameters)
        {
            sqlPar = sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(kv.Key, kv.Value);
            sqlPar.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        }

        sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        returnParameters = GetOutputParameters(sqlcmd.Parameters);
        transaction.Commit();
    }
    catch (System.Exception e)
    {
        var tt = e.Message;
        try
        {
            if (transaction != null)
                transaction.Rollback();
        }
        catch { }
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (sqlConn != null)
        {
            if (sqlConn.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                sqlConn.Close();
            }
        }
        if (transaction != null)
        {
            IDisposable dispose = transaction as IDisposable;
            if (dispose != null) { dispose.Dispose(); }
        }
        if (sqlcmd != null)
        {
            IDisposable dispose = sqlcmd as IDisposable;
            if (dispose != null) { dispose.Dispose(); }
        }
        if (sqlConn != null)
        {
            IDisposable dispose = sqlConn as IDisposable;
            if (dispose != null) { dispose.Dispose(); }
        }
    }
    return returnParameters;
}

private Dictionary<string, object> GetOutputParameters(SqlParameterCollection paramCollection)
{
    var returnParameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    foreach (SqlParameter par in paramCollection)
    {
        if ((par.Direction == ParameterDirection.Output) || (par.Direction == ParameterDirection.ReturnValue))
        {
            returnParameters.Add(par.ParameterName, par.Value);
        }
    }
    return returnParameters;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

*(See also comments in code)*

**GetRefNo**

Create case-insensitive dictionaries right away as you ignore the case later anyway:

```
public SubmissionHeaderDTO GetRefNo()
{
    // tell the dictionaries how to compare the keys
    var inPrms = new Dictionary<string, object>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
    {
        // ...
    };


    var outPrms = new Dictionary<string, object>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
    {
        // ...
    };

    var refNo = DBHelper.ExecSP(Constants.SPNames.SubmissionHeaderInsert, inPrms, outPrms);

    SubmissionHeaderDTO result = DictionaryToObject<SubmissionHeaderDTO>(refNo);

    return result;

}
```

**DictionaryToObject**

You don't need to call `.GetType().GetProperties()` over and over. You already have retrieved the properties at the beginning. It might be a real performance hit if you do it frequently. Luckily this can be easily avoided.

```
private static T DictionaryToObject<T>(IDictionary<string, object> dict) where T : new()
{
    // use a meaningfull name for the instance of T
    var result = new T();

    var properties = 
        typeof(T)
        .GetProperties()
        // filter the properties hier not in the loop, it's easier to modify and understand
        .Where(p => dict.ContainsKey(p.Name));

    foreach (var property in properties)
    {       
        // you can now directly get the value for the property
        var value = dict[property.Name]

        var propretyType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(property.PropertyType) ?? property.PropertyType;

        var convertedValue = Convert.ChangeType(value, propretyType);

        // there's no need to GetType.GetProperties agian, just set the value
        property.SetValue(result, convertedValue)
    }

    return result;
}
```

**ExecuteQuery**

Your code will look nicer and simpler if you use the `using` instead of the lengthy `finally` block:

```
public Dictionary<string, object> ExecuteQuery(
    string storedProcedure, 
    Dictionary<string, object> parameters,
    Dictionary<string, object> outParameters)
{       
    // the usings will gracefully dispose/close everything disposable
    using (var sqlConn = new SqlConnection(Configuration.DBConnection))
    {
        sqlConn.Open();

        // if this is a select I doubt you need a transaction for this
        using (var transaction = sqlConn.BeginTransaction("Results"))
        using (var sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(storedProcedure, sqlConn, transaction))
        {

            sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            // use var where possible
            foreach (var kv in parameters)
            {
                sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(kv.Key, kv.Value);
            }

            foreach (var kv in outParameters)
            {
                // no helper variables needed here
                sqlcmd
                    .Parameters
                    .AddWithValue(kv.Key, kv.Value)
                    .Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            }

            try
            {
                sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                var result = GetOutputParameters(sqlcmd.Parameters);

                transaction.Commit();
                return result;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                transaction.Rollback();
                throw;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Spot-on with what I was starting to write up. One thing I was going to mention - there's a haphazard mixing of `Dictionary` and `IDictionary` in the OP's code. I would standardize on developing to interfaces and make sure things are declared as `IDictionary` for parameters and return types.

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer indeed, there's a small chaos. Now, two years later, I'd do it exactly as you suggest too ;-]